# Do-while loop won't work

Tags: java, string, do-while

I'm having a problem with my while loop. The program asks the user for their name and after the user have made their input, the program asks how many times you would like to print the input.

I've been stuck on my while-loop for quite a time and can only make it work if I do something like: `} while (antal > some random number)`

```
package uppg2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Uppg2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ant = new Scanner(System.in);
        int antal;
        String namn;
        System.out.print("Whats your name?: ");
        namn = name.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How many times u wanna print ur name?: ");
        antal = ant.nextInt();
        do {

            System.out.print(namn);

        } while (????);
        antal++;
        namn = null;
        antal = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop? `for(int i=0;i<antal;++i)`

Comment: Does it have to be a `do-while`, a `for-loop` would be easier and a `while-loop` would be safer then `do-while`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I assume the homework question requires that it is a do while loop.

Comment: @PeterElliott That might be the case, and if it is, it's a bad one as it doesn't allow for a pre-condition check before entering the loop, meaning even if the user enters `0`, the loop will run once - IMHO

Comment: add an if statement before the loop.  It might be that the student has to write the same thing as a for, a do, and a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be rather a use-case for a for-loop like some others suggested. But when you insist on using a while loop:

```
int counter = 0; // a variable which counts how often the while loop has run

do {
    System.out.print( namn ); // do what you want to do
    counter++                 // increase the counter
} while (counter < antal)     // check if the desired number of iterations is reached
```

When you don't need the value of `antal` anymore when the loop is over, you can also do it without the counter variable and just reduce antal every loop and check if it has reached 0.

```
do {
    System.out.print( namn );
    antal--;
} while (antal > 0)
```

Comment: yeah, the thing is my teacher told me to use do-while, and since im studying from a distance, i have not really any classmate to ask for a solution, so i come to u guys :P

Answer (score 3):

I personally would use a for loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < antal; i++){
    System.out.println(namn);
}
```

Comment: antal is an int... no need to do parseInt on it.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I assumed it to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

You could count `antal` down (`antal--`) until it is 1.  Not sure if it is OK to destroy the value in `antal` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
package uppg2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Uppg2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int antal;
    String namn;
    System.out.print("Whats your name?: ");
    namn = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("How many times u wanna print ur name?: ");
    antal = in.nextInt();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < antal){

            System.out.print( namn );
            i++;

    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

Tell me if that works. Basically, you need an increment counter to ensure that it only prints out the desired amount of times. Since we start counting at 0, we don't need to ensure that it goes till it equals the print time, but while it still is under it.

Answer (score 1):

you would have to have a counter that is incremented inside of your do-while loop, and perform your comparison against that value

it would make your loop loop something like:

```
antal = ant.nextInt();
int i = 0;
do{ 

            System.out.print( namn );
            i++; 

    }while (i < antal);
```

note that because it's a do-while loop, you will always print the name at least once, even if the user enters zero.  To prevent this, you would need to use a for or while loop, as described by other answerers, or use an if condition around the `System.out.println` call to check if antal is zero.

Also, if you don't care what antal is at the end, you can use TofuBeer's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to a similar problem. See if you can't translate it into your problem:

```
// How many times to I want to do something?
int max = 40;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    // Do something!
}
```